# Group data from two database tables into a one-to-many, parent-child relationship

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, grouping

I want to merge data from one query into the results of another query with a one to many relationship.  The relationship will be 1 task to many cards.

I want to create something like this:

```
Array
 (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => open
        [task] => Array
                 (
                 [0] => Array
                 (
                     [id] => 2
                     [project_id] => 1
                     [name] => task 2 from pro1
                     [card] => 1
                 )
                 )
      )

)
```

with this:

Array 1:

```
Array
 (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => open
    )

 )
```

Array 2 :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [project_id] => 1
        [name] => task 2 from pro1
        [card] => 1
    )
)
```

Let's assume array 1 is a card array and array 2 is task array. There are multiple cards and tasks. I need to set a task at a card where it belongs and that's why I have a card id in both arrays. If the card array has id 1 and task also has [card] => 1 then it is settled in that array.

Here is my code:

```
$get_card_qry = "select * from tts_card where project_id = '1' ";
$get_card_res = $conn -> query($get_card_qry);


$cad = $task = array();
while($row = $get_card_res -> fetch_assoc())
{
    array_push($cad, $row);
    $get_task_qry = "select * from tts_task where card = '".$row['id']."' ";
    $get_task_res = $conn -> query($get_task_qry);
    while($row1 = $get_task_res -> fetch_assoc())
    {
        array_push($task , $row1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `[]` notation. Please, start with php.net manuals.

Comment: could be there multiple tasks for one card?

Comment: Yes there are multiple tasks for one card @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Anything not working with the given code? Also, be warned that your `SELECT` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using regular `foreach` loops:

```
$cards = [0 => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'open']];
$tasks = [  // add one more item/task for complex case
    0 => ['id' => 2, 'project_id' => 1,  'name' => 'task 2 from pro1', 'card' => 1],
    1 => ['id' => 3, 'project_id' => 2,  'name' => 'task 3 from pro1', 'card' => 1]
];

foreach ($cards as &$card) {
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        if ($task['card'] === $card['id']) $card['task'][] = $task;
    }
}

print_r($cards);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => open
            [task] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [project_id] => 1
                            [name] => task 2 from pro1
                            [card] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [project_id] => 2
                            [name] => task 3 from pro1
                            [card] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Relate the data into row in the SQL, then use temporary first level ids in PHP to form the multidimensional array.

On the first encounter of a card id, create the parent array.  All encounters of a given card id, push the task data into the parent array.  Remove the grouping key with `array_values()` after the loop finished.

Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/TC))

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT tts_card.id,
       tts_card.name,
       tts_task.id          task_id,
       tts_task.project_id,
       tts_task.name        task_name,
       tts_task.card
FROM tts_card
JOIN tts_task ON tts_card.id = tts_task.card
WHERE project_id = '1'
SQL;

$result = [];
foreach ($mysqli->query($sql) as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['id']])) {
        $result[$row['id']] = [
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'task' => [],
        ];
    }
    $result[$row['id']]['task'][] = [
        'id' => $row['task_id'],
        'project_id' => $row['project_id'],
        'name' => $row['task_name'],
        'card' => $row['card'],            
    ];
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```